# A choice between singular and plural

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> A significant decrease in the score was observed 1 and 2 months after the intervention.
>   Significant decreases in the scores were observed 1 and 2 months after the intervention.

Which of the above is grammatically correct? 
Would the latter correct because the decreases observed from different time points are apparently different kinds of things?
+ Should I put 'at' and make the sentence '~~ observed at 1 and 2 months ~~'? Or is it alright without 'at'?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You really have a choice in this context. There is no correct answer.

However, if the decrease was much the same after each month, and there was a single score, it might incline you to use the singular.

If the decreases varied widely, if there was a series of decreases rather than just one, and if there was more than one score, you should use the plural.

It's fine without **at**. You could insert it if you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Ronald Sole has given an excellent answer to the specific question asked, but both sentences suffer from the same potential ambiguity.

Old score = 100
Score at end of month 1 = 80
Score at end of month 2 = 80

There was a material decrease (20%) relative to the same base in both months. Either sentence reflects that.

Old score = 100
Score at end of month 1 = 80
Score at end of month 2 = 64

There was a material decrease (20%) relative to different bases in each month. Either sentence reflects that.

But those are two different situations entirely.

For the first situation

> There was a material decrease in the scores at the end of the first month, but no further material changes at the end of the second month.

For the second situation

> There was a material decrease in the scores at the end of the first month, and a further material decrease in the scores at the end of the second month.

Now this answer will be pettifogging if this text supplements a table or a graph. In that context, either of your sentences will be interpreted correctly. If, however, you are trying to provide a purely qualitative summary of something that is inherently quantitative, either sentence is subject to misinterpretation.